# Sort output objects by order of input avoiding O(n^2)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Given two arrays. I want to sort the objects in the output by the order of values in the input. The result should return an array of objects sorted by the order of items in the input array.

NB: You can have two objects in the result that has a key with the same value, the most important thing is the order of items in the input.

```
const input = [
    "app_id",
    "app_total",      
    "app_name",   
    "app_number",
    "app_date",
    "app_bank",
    "app_city",
    "total_tax",
    "total_paid",
    "science_score",
    "science_check"
]
```

```
const output = [{
    app_id: 'APP-EBF02',
    app_total: null,
    app_name: null,
    app_number: null,
    app_date: '12/19/2019 19:28:18',
    app_bank: null,
    app_city: 'New York',
    science_score: '830.0000',
    science_check: null,
    total_tax: 221.94000000000008,
    total_paid: 168.7854
},
{
    app_id: 'APP-4E0B2',
    app_total: null,
    app_name: null,
    app_number: '3',
    app_date: '12/20/2019 22:04:13',
    app_bank: null,
    app_city: 'New York',
    science_score: '830.0000',
    science_check: null,
    total_tax: 299.64,
    total_paid: 0
},
{
    app_id: 'APP-77929',
    app_total: null,
    app_name: null,
    app_number: 'e',
    app_date: '12/23/2019 20:09:49',
    app_bank: null,
    app_city: 'New York',
    science_score: '830.0000',
    science_check: null,
    total_tax: 110.70000000000003,
    total_paid: 0
 }
]
```

The result should be sorted by the order of the input. Sample result given below:

```
const result = [{
    app_id: 'APP-EBF02',
    app_total: null,
    app_name: null,
    app_number: null,
    app_date: '12/19/2019 19:28:18',
    app_bank: null,
    app_city: 'New York',
    total_tax: 221.94000000000008,
    total_paid: 168.7854,
    science_score: '830.0000',
    science_check: null
}, {
    app_id: 'APP-4E0B2',
    app_total: null,
    app_name: null,
    app_number: '3',
    app_date: '12/20/2019 22:04:13',
    app_bank: null,
    app_city: 'New York',
    total_tax: 299.64,
    total_paid: 0,
    science_score: '830.0000',
    science_check: null
}, {
    app_id: 'APP-77929',
    app_total: null,
    app_name: null,
    app_number: 'e',
    app_date: '12/23/2019 20:09:49',
    app_bank: null,
    app_city: 'New York',
    total_tax: 110.70000000000003,
    total_paid: 0,
    science_score: '830.0000',
    science_check: null
}]
```

This is what I came up with

```
function sorted(input, output){
 const result = [];
 const store = {};

 input.forEach((res,index) => {
   store[res] = index;
 })

 output.forEach((res) => {
   Object.keys(res).forEach((el,i) => {
     result[store[el]] = res[el]
   })
 })

 return result;
}

console.log(sorted(input,output));
```

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not possible to order the keys in an object. What is the purpose of  ordering the object keys?

Comment: Yea thanks for replying. Basically I want to maintain the order of result based on the input entered. Let's say a user selects a list of items which is the input then after some operations(queries in a table + custom calculations(tax_paid,total_paid, etc)) after which the result is merged together to give the output above. I want to be able to maintain the order of the input entered in the result